# Show MQTT data in Flask template

Tags: python, flask, mqtt

I'm using `Flask-MQTT` and I'm able to receive messages. I have been following the following [guide](https://github.com/stlehmann/Flask-MQTT). When I receive a message, I want to display the data in a template, but am unable to do so. Below is the code I have.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_mqtt import Mqtt

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='./views')
app.config['MQTT_BROKER_URL'] = 'URL'
app.config['MQTT_BROKER_PORT'] = 0000
app.config['MQTT_REFRESH_TIME'] = 1.0

mqtt = Mqtt(app)


@mqtt.on_connect()
def handle_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    mqtt.subscribe('#')


@mqtt.on_message()
def handle_mqtt_message(client, userdata, message):
    data = dict(
        topic=message.topic,
        payload=message.payload.decode()
    )


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('graph.html')
```

How can I show new data from MQTT in the `graph.html` template I have created?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a socket to allow real-time communication between the server and web client/template. The [Flask-MQTT documentation](https://flask-mqtt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#interact-with-socketio) already provides a neat example on how to implement this server-side using [Flask-SocketIO](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Client-side, use the [Javascript library of SocketIO](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#Socket).

Server-side, every time a MQTT message is received, it should push a `mqtt_message` event  (containing the message data) to the socket using `socketio.emit()`.

Client-side, `socket.on()` is used to listen for `mqtt_message` events and handle a new event.

Below is a bare-bones working implementation based on your code. Here I'm connecting to `test.mosquitto.org` for testing purposes. Every time a new MQTT message is received, its data is appended to the template on a new line (and also logged to the JavaScript console).

Server-side:

```
import eventlet
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_mqtt import Mqtt
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

eventlet.monkey_patch()

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='./views')
app.config['MQTT_BROKER_URL'] = 'test.mosquitto.org'
app.config['MQTT_BROKER_PORT'] = 1883
app.config['MQTT_REFRESH_TIME'] = 1.0

mqtt = Mqtt(app)
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@mqtt.on_connect()
def handle_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    mqtt.subscribe('#')

@mqtt.on_message()
def handle_mqtt_message(client, userdata, message):
    data = dict(
        topic=message.topic,
        payload=message.payload.decode()
    )
    # emit a mqtt_message event to the socket containing the message data
    socketio.emit('mqtt_message', data=data)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('graph.html')

@mqtt.on_log()
def handle_logging(client, userdata, level, buf):
    print(level, buf)

socketio.run(app, host='localhost', port=5000, use_reloader=True, debug=True)
```

Client-side (template `views/graph.html`):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.3.6/socket.io.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);

    // listen for mqtt_message events
    // when a new message is received, log and append the data to the page
    socket.on('mqtt_message', function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      var text = '(' + data['topic'] + ' qos: ' + data['qos'] + ') ' + data['payload'];
      $('#subscribe_messages').append(text + '<br><br>');
    })
  });
</script>

<div id="subscribe_messages"></div>
```

Here's what it looks like:

[image: client-side output]

Comment: Ah, I see. I was maybe looking for a more built-in Flask-ish way of solving this, but then SocketIO is the way to go, apparently. Thank you very much for your good answer!

Comment: This helped mea lot, I was stuck for a month!! Thank you so much!